# Ruby choose randomly several options with rand method

Tags: ruby

My code:

```
alea = ["x", " "]
num = alea.length
choice = rand(num)
veinte = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i in veinte
    puts alea[choice]
end
```

I want that my code choose randomly several options y no only one. For example:

```
x

x
x

x
x
x
```

how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array#sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) was invented for this purpose:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map do |elem| 
  [elem, [true, false].sample]
end.to_h
#⇒ {
#   1 => true,
#  10 => false,
#   2 => true,
#   3 => true,
#   4 => false,
#   5 => true,
#   6 => false,
#   7 => true,
#   8 => false,
#   9 => false
#}
```

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map do |elem| 
  puts ["x", " "].sample
end

Comment: If you just need to `put` `x`-es or spaces, `1.upto(10).each { puts ["x", " "].sample }` is more applicable (or even `10.times { puts ... }`.) You should not `map` when you don’t need a result. `each` is quite sufficient. You might omit the block variable when you don’t need it as well.

Comment: Iterating over an array just to do something 10 times is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

It seems all you need is a certain number of randomly selected items. In this case, simply use the block-form Array constructor:

```
Array.new(10){ ["x", " "].sample }

#=>[" ", " ", "x", " ", "x", " ", "x", " ", "x", "x"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your code:

```
alea = ["x", " "]
num = alea.length
choice = rand(num)
veinte = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
veinte.map { puts alea[rand(alea.length)] }
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting is correct according to the code you have written :

```
alea = ["x", " "]  # => Array on only two elements
num = alea.length  # => 2
choice = rand(num) # => rand(2) will only output either 0 or 1 which will always output either alea[0] or alea[1] which is " " or "x"
```

If you really want a random value from an Array then either use sample method of Array class as suggested by @mudasobwa